# Which plot.ly json property enables all hover data to be displayed when hovering over one line

Tags: javascript, json, matlab, plotly

I am plotting two lines on a graph in Matlab, and converting it to `plot.ly` using the Matlab library. When I use the `'strip' = false` json property, it preserves the Matlab layout. However, it removes the nice feature where by you get all the data when you hover over one line. When `'strip' = false`, you only get data pertaining to the line you hover over.

Does anyone know how to use `'strip' = false` and yet retain all the hover overs?

Sample code in `Matlab`:

```
X = linspace(0,2*pi,50)';
Y = [cos(X), 0.5*sin(X)];
figure
plot(X,Y)
```

Then generate two `plot.ly` plots:

```
fig2plotly(gcf, 'strip', 0);
fig2plotly(gcf, 'strip', 1);
```

These can be respectively found at:

https://plot.ly/~alexdp/0

https://plot.ly/~alexdp/2

Note the difference in the hover over behaviour.

Comment: You may need to contact them about this, it seems undefined/unwanted behaviour. probably a bug

Comment: thanks, I guess I can raise an issue in github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you convert a matlab figure to Plotly Figure with `strip=false`, the `hovermode` attribute is set to `closest` by default, hence it only shows data pertaining to nearest curve on hovering. To override this behaviour:

```
X = linspace(0,2*pi,50);
Y = [cos(X), 0.5*sin(X)];
figure
plot(X,Y)

% Convert the chart..
plotly_fig = fig2plotly(gcf, 'strip', 0)

% Set hovermode to blank (basically disable the attribute)
plotly_fig.layout.hovermode=''

% Send the updated figure to plotly:
resp = plotly(plotly_fig)
url = resp.url
```